# Is there a generic way to implement column names?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm trying to implement the django-import-export library in a generic way.

When setting the fields property in the Meta class there isn't a way to set the column names. When setting a `Field()` on the `ModelResource` directly it is possible. But as far as I know, you can't create those in a generic way.

This is what I already have:

```
def create_resource(django_model, model_fields):
    class ModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            model = django_model
            fields = model_fields

    return ModelResource()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate with pseudo code of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field

def create_resource(django_model, django_fields):
    class ModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            model = django_model
            fields = ()

    resource = ModelResource()
    for attribute, name in django_fields:
        resource.fields[attribute] = Field(attribute=attribute, column_name=name)

    return resource
```

The `create_resource` will create the `ModelResource` with all the `Fields` from the `django_fields` parameter.
The `django_fields` variable will look like this:

```
django_fields = [
            ("id", "ID"),
            ("first_name", "First name"),
            ("last_name", "Last name"),
            ("group__name", "Group name"),
        ]
```